# scrapy shell for xpath //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "S3Uucc", " " ))]

Tags: xpath, scrapy

New to python, scrapy and xpath. And struggling with it. 
I have a xpath: `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "S3Uucc", " " ))]`
I am trying past couple of hours to get the response from it and nothing i get. Can anyone help me creating useful response xpath string that can return me data? I tried:

```
>> response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "S3Uucc", " " ))]').getall() 
used get() but no result for the above

>> response.xpath ('//*[@class="S3Uucc"]').getall()

>> response.xpath('//span[@class="S3Uucc"]'.getall()
No result.
```

The actual url is from google https://www.google.com/search?q=siteurl%3Awww.google.co.nz+%22print+%7C+design%22+%22NZ%22+%22%40gmail.com%22&rlz=1C1CHWA_enNZ876NZ876&oq=site&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i61j69i65l3j69i61l2.6357j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Appreciate the help!!

Comment: I tried this in my scrapy shell :
response.xpath ('//span[@class="S3Uucc"]/text()').get() 
it says : 
invalid predicate in 
response.xpath ('//span[@class="S3Uucc"]/text()').get()

Answer (score 1):

Tested successfully in firefox console :

```
'//span[@class="S3Uucc"]/text()'
```

Comment: thanks alot, but how are you testing in browser? i m bit new to all this. if they are working in browser then i suspect they would work in my code for sure.

Comment: `$x('//span[@class="S3Uucc"]/text()')[0]` (works with chrome too)

Comment: Better to use `contains(concat))` for class names. `//span[@class="S3Uucc"]` will match only `<span class="S3Uucc">`. `span` with multiple class names won't be matched.